# How to properly append azure blob storage?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage

I need to append a lot of information to blob storage. Now it looks like this:

```js
    async append(filename, data) {
        const client = this.containerClient.getAppendBlobClient(filename);
        await client.createIfNotExists();
        await client.appendBlock(data, data.length);
    }
```

Is the way optimal or I can do better?

Comment: Actually, it works very slowly

Answer (score 2):

- As per this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/appendblobclient?view=azure-node-latest#@azure-storage-blob-appendblobclient-appendblock), your code is correct

> Actually, it works very slowly

- Numerous minor appends will severely fragment the blob, which makes the reads more time-consuming than writes.

As per this document [Avoid duplicate or delayed appends](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/append-block#avoid-duplicate-or-delayed-appends)

> The client can also avoid duplicates or delays by checking the `ETag` conditionally, by using `If-Match`.

- Maximum size of AppendBlob is 195 GB
- Block blobs in Azure Storage have two [latency metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-latency#latency-metrics-for-block-blobs) available - **End-to-end (E2E) latency** and **Server latency**

Please refer [Poor performance of Azure Storage - Append Blobs](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/83d83158-87e3-4d09-b818-753876f7a536/poor-performance-of-azure-storage-append-blobs?forum=windowsazuredata)